# Adding new ad network adapter to AdMob Mediation, what happens to old clients?

Tags: java, android, admob

I would like to add [AppBrain's AppLift](http://www.appbrain.com/info/sdk) ad network to my existing [android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.miumeet.android.client) through [AdMob mediation](http://www.admob.com).

Do I need to create a new mediation ID for this new version or can I keep using the same mediation id?

What happens to old app versions (that don't have [AppLift](http://www.appbrain.com/info/sdk)) if I allocate traffic to [AppLift](http://www.appbrain.com/info/sdk)?

I found a great [explanation for AdWhirl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882949/can-i-add-a-new-adwhirl-ad-network-for-an-existing-app), does [AdMob mediation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882949/can-i-add-a-new-adwhirl-ad-network-for-an-existing-app) differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Admob mediation layer handles this for you.

I assume that you have found the instructions on integrating [AppLift into Admob mediation](http://www.appbrain.com/info/sdk-admob-mediation-applift). When you add the new Custom Event with classname `com.appbrain.mediation.AdmobAdapter`, Admob will offer this to your app. For older versions of the app, Admob will gracefully detect that this class is not present and choose the next option that you specify on the Admob console.

Comment: To be complete - if you allocate via `eCPM`, AdMob will just ignore AppLift for old versions of your app.  If you allocate via `percentages`, AdMob will ignore your AppLift percentages and normalize all other percentages for old versions of your app.